# I have deleted Oracle listener from windows services

Tags: oracle

I am using oracle 11 express edition and I have deleted the Oracle Listener service from windows services mistakenly and now I can't connect to the database.
Could someone help me to recreate the service again using command line.

Answer (score 7):

**Test case deleting  Listener and creating service manually**

```
C:\>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 04-AUG-2019 02:58:56

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                04-AUG-2019 02:57:36
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 1 min. 23 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\XXX\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=XXX)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=XXX)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

C:\>sc query type=service | findstr Oracle*
SERVICE_NAME: OracleXETNSListener
DISPLAY_NAME: OracleXETNSListener
SERVICE_NAME: OracleServiceXE
DISPLAY_NAME: OracleServiceXE
```

**I'll stop listener and delete the service**

```
C:\>sc delete OracleXETNSListener
[SC] DeleteService SUCCESS

C:\>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 04-AUG-2019 03:00:31

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXX)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
```

**Creating service manually**

```
C:\>sc create OracleXETNSListener binpath=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\BIN\tnslsnr.exe
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

C:\>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 04-AUG-2019 03:01:20

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\XXX\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=XXX)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                04-AUG-2019 03:01:22
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 1 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\XXX\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=XXX)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Optional:Once the service is created go to services and configure service to auto start

Comment: Thanks a lot. Creating a new TNS listener worked for me. I don't know how my TNS listener get deleted or disappeared. but by creating new listener did everything correct.